# Problema con session_start() en PHP

Tags: php, sesiones

Estoy teniendo un problema y no acierto a ver el fallo. Lo bueno es que he conseguido reproducir el fallo en una situación muy simple.

Tengo dos ficheros **PHP**.

El primero, **index.php** es así:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es-ES">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Chk login</title>
    <script>
        function hacerPost(ruta, params){
        var body = document.body;
        form = document.createElement('form');
        form.method = 'POST';
        form.action = ruta;
        form.name = 'jsform';
        for (var x = 0; x < params.length; x++) {
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.type = 'hidden';
            input.name = params[x][0];
            input.id = params[x][0];
            input.value = params[x][1];

            form.appendChild(input);
        }
        body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $_SESSION["gestor"]="gestor123";
        $_SESSION["rol"]="rol456";
    ?>
    <script>
        hacerPost('./prueba_sesion.php',[["idgestor","1000"]]);
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Este fichero, crea dos sesiones, la sesión *gestor* y la sesión *rol*, y después pasa un parámetro por *POST* (en este ejemplo el parámetro es `idgestor` y se envía mediante la función `hacerPost()`) al segundo fichero *PHP* que debe recibir el parámetro *POST* y las dos sesiones.

Este segundo fichero, **prueba_sesion.php** es:

```
<?php session_start();
echo "===================================<br>";
echo "Sesion gestor: ". $_SESSION["gestor"]."<br>";
echo "Sesion rol: ".$_SESSION["rol"]."<br>";
echo "Post idgestor: ".$_POST["idgestor"]."<br>";
```

Corriendo en *localhost* con *XAMPP* funciona perfectamente y saca por pantalla los valores de las sesiones (`gestor123` y `rol456`). Sin embargo, y aquí el problema, en el servidor no funciona. Sí, recibe el parámetro *POST* correctamente, pero las sesiones no y en cambio, recibo el error (en un fichero **error.log**):

> [09-Nov-2018 23:21:11 Europe/Madrid] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in ..../pruebas/inicio_sesion/prueba_sesion.php on line 1

He estado repasando preguntas típicas en este sentido y el error más habitual es el de no poner en primer lugar `session_start()`, pero creo que no es el caso, porque está en la primera línea y he comprobado que no hay caracteres extraños antes, y además está la paradoja de que sí, funciona en *localhost*.

Tanto en *localhost* como en el servidor tengo *PHP 7.2*. He probado en 2 servidores distintos y no funciona.

¿Cómo resuelvo este problema de sesiones?

Comment: He probado tu código tal cual y me funciona.

Comment: Gracias Cedano por probarlo. Entonces, si funciona en unos sitios y en otros no, debe ser problema de la configuración de php. ¿Alguien sabe qué parámetro puede influir en la sesión?

Comment: Lo único que puede variar es que tengas más cosas en tus scripts. Yo lo he probado tal cual lo compartes. O que te estés equivocando de archivo en el action del formulario, enviando a otro archivo que esté incorrecto y no te hayas dado cuenta. Mi archivo del action estaba en la misma carpeta que el archivo principal, pero no creo que eso influya.

Comment: No hay nada más. Los dos únicos ficheros que hay son los dos php que he puesto, sin una sola línea más de código. :/

Comment: Bueno, ahora que me fijo y para ser totalmente exactos, en el index.php he olvidado cerrar la etiqueta </html> en el código que he puesto. Pero en mi caso sí que está puesta, es un error de transcripción.

Comment: ¿Y has verificado que el archivo del action que estás revisando es el correcto y no otro en otra carpeta? ¿Ningún problema de caché o algo por el estilo?

Comment: El archivo del action es './prueba_sesion.php' ubicado en la misma carpeta. La petición post la construyo a partir de la función hacerPost() que envía la ruta del archivo action y los parámetros en un form oculto. Esta función la utilizo a menudo y funciona bien. Lo del caché, no sé comprobarlo. He limpiado la caché del firefox...

Comment: Haré alguna prueba utilizando otra forma de hacer post, quizá el problema venga de ahí

Comment: Pues si el archivo está en la misma carpeta como dices no sé qué hace el `./` en tu ruta ¿? Deberías poner el nombre del archivo sin más. Y, si se trata de cambiar de técnica, yo usaría `cURL` en tu caso sin dudarlo ni un segundo.

Comment: Generalmente este error ocurre cuando PHP lanza un warning y por tanto, modifica la página antes de ejecutarse el session_start, ¿no hay ningún mensaje de warning cuando ejecutas directamente prueba_sesion.php? prueba a ocultar los warnings de php a ver si así. También deberías comprobar de lanzar directamente el script y ver el código fuente a ver que sale.

Comment: Gracias track3r por tu ayuda, pero viendo que el problema era totalmente irracional, decidí dejarlo y tirar por otro lado. Ya no utilizo sesiones, guardo unos datos en una base de datos mysql y los consulto. Al cabo de x minutos, los datos pierden validez.